# simple multiple user selections/options

Tags: php, mysql, load, performance

I see many implementations such as the Facebook like, forum karma, mark as read on forum posts and other simple options and selections available to multiple users on a given item.

I know I can implement this in mysql by creating a table which links say post IDs to liker user IDs for say, a like system.

My problem is, on a page with lots of posts, I will have to make a lookup for every post. I use prepared statements so that makes it faster for me.

Is there another way to implement these systems, if not, are there optimisations like database types or other tweaks that can make this faster?

Basically, is there a powerful, fast implementation of a many to many database interaction.

*EDIT*** 
I'm using opera mini and so I have issues with the ajax and js for commenting

---

Right now, I have a table with two columns. One for user id and the other for post id.  Both are indexed and are used in foreign key constraints.
I'm thinking of making a compound primary key across the two.

My main issue is for the karma. I allow users to vote on each post. The problem is, for each post, I need to get the total votes, determine if a user has voted to either allow the user to or not to vote.

My site allows many users to host their own sites and so I need to seriously optimize this.

Someone suggested I use memory tables for this.

---

NOTE**** 
I can't use memcached.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: Assuming "likes" are changed rarely and read often, a system like memcached works really, *really* well and makes it very fast to look up 50 items for a page.

Comment: +1 for memcache -- Facebook has even released their optimized version that they use, most likely for this exact kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest using something else than a MySQL db. I've written an opensocial app which had both heavy writes and reads to a database. It all started with a MySQL DB, I even switched to a dedicated master slave replication setup. But to no avail, it was expensive and it didn't scale very well.

The final solution was to use a [NoSQL](http://nosql-database.org/) db which made the most out of RAM. My decision was [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) which has an activy community and solved my problem very well. MongoDB proofed to be highly scalable.

Comment: I have been looking at mongodb and honestly, it is worth using. Its schemaless structure is just great for almost all my applications. i tend to like denormailizing sometimes and storing serialised arrays. enjoy the 50.

Comment: Thank you, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Still a little hazy about what you got so far, but I'll start it off and keep adding stuff if need be:

1. Make sure you're Indexing
2. Minimum lookups -so you get the list
   of posts that will pop up, use that
   list to match the like's, if they've viewed the article etc.
3. Using numbers - make sure all your
   comparisons are with numbers
4. If you're running queries, don't run a single query for each post
5. Is there a limit in your query? - make sure you use that
6. De-normalization is not a sin
7. You can partition your databases to decrease lookups (e.g. if data is older than 60 days and barely touched, move it to a secondary database/table, so the size of your table is not huge)

e.g. `SELECT * FROM user_liked WHERE post_id IN (1,2,3)`
instead of

```
SELECT * FROM user_liked WHERE post_id = 1
```

Comment: Although some people might not agree, denormalization can be useful sometimes, like keeping the total number of people who liked a post

Answer (score 0):

Philipp Keller wrote a bunch of articles on tag systems based on MYSQL a few years ago. Just as Like-ing, Tagging is establishing a many-to-many relationship between a thing (tag, article being liked) and a user. The logic in his articles should be directly applicable to your problem as well.

Check out the comments as well.

- http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html
  Database Schemas for Tagging solutions
- http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/05/tags-with-mysql-fulltext.html
  Abusing the MySQL FULLTEXT indices for tagging and tag search (requires MyISAM, I'd not go there).
- http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/06/tagsystems-performance-tests.html
  Performance Tests of tagging systems

Comment: Unfortunately these links are broken.